# Beautiful soup pagination

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

sorry if this is obvious but I'm trying to do a jobs spider for indeed which pulls details from the individual details pages as well.

I'm struggling quite a bit and I'm a complete beginner at this. I've tried a few variations and this one is probably the closest I've managed to get to having the spider yield results from the individual job pages. However, the results from the details page are pulled in random columns below, and not after the other variables.

It also doesn't let me clean up the text at all, and using .text and .strip() yields an error.

Would someone be able to look at the code and see what I'm doing wrong?

Full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import scrapy
import requests
import csv
import time
import os
pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

with open(r'C:\Users\', 'a', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_print = csv.writer(f_output)

    file_is_empty = os.stat(r'x.csv').st_size == 0
    if file_is_empty:
        csv_print.writerow(['Title', 'Company', 'Location', 'Salary', 'Summary', 'Link', 'Description'])

    for page in pages:
        source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+remote&l=United+States&limit=50&sr=directhire{}'.format(page)).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

        results = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "result"})

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):

            try:
                title = jobs.h2.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                title = None
            print('Title:', title)

            try:
                company = jobs.span.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                company = None
            print('Company:', company)

            try:
                location = jobs.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                location = None
            print('Location:', location)

            try:
                salary = jobs.find('span', class_='no-wrap').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
            print('Salary:', salary)

            try:
                summary = soup.find('div', class_='summary').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                summary = None
            print('Summary:', summary)

            link = jobs.a['href']
            link = ("https://www.indeed.com" + link)
            print('Link:', link)

            **page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            job_description = soup.find('div', id_='jobDescriptionText')
            print(soup)**

            csv_print.writerow((title, company, location, salary, summary, link, job_description))

            print('--------')

            time.sleep(0.5)
```

The part I have issues with is:

```
            **page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            job_description = soup.find('div', id_='jobDescriptionText')
            print(soup)**
```

Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is, that you are using `id_` with underscore. The correct parameter is just `id`:

```
        page = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').get_text(strip=True)  # <-- note only id=, NOT id_=
        print('job_description:', job_description)
```

Another detail is, some links are using full paths, so change this part:

```
        link = jobs.a['href']
        if 'http' not in link:   # <-- note the if
            link = ("https://www.indeed.com" + link)
        print('Link:', link)
```

---

EDIT: This prints all information from all pages:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pages = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

for page in pages:
    source = requests.get('https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+scientist+remote&l=United+States&limit=50&sr=directhire{}'.format(page)).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

    for jobs in soup.find_all(class_='result'):

            try:
                title = jobs.h2.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                title = None
            print('Title:', title)

            try:
                company = jobs.span.text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                company = None
            print('Company:', company)

            try:
                location = jobs.find('span', class_='location').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                location = None
            print('Location:', location)

            try:
                salary = jobs.find('span', class_='no-wrap').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                salary = None
            print('Salary:', salary)

            try:
                summary = soup.find('div', class_='summary').text.strip()
            except Exception as e:
                summary = None
            print('Summary:', summary)

            link = jobs.a['href']
            if 'http' not in link:   # <-- note the if
                link = ("https://www.indeed.com" + link)
            print('Link:', link)

            page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            job_description = soup.find('div', id='jobDescriptionText').get_text(strip=True)  # <-- note only id=, NOT id_=
            print('job_description:', job_description)

            print('--------')

            time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: That's perfect, it works very well. The only thing is, with this it no longer works through multiple pages. Would it be this new element causing the issue?

Comment: @Alex232 I added a version that prints all pages in my answer.